# Disable button when clicked

Tags: php, button, onclick

As you can see in the code below, I have 2 flags `my` and `hk`.
When I click on the `hk` flag, it will redirect to the `hk` page and at the same time will disable the `hk` button to show the difference from other buttons.

So，what php code do I use to disable only the button that is clicked?

```
<button id="btn_my" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" 
  onClick='location = "<?php echo url_realurl();?>/results/view/all/M"'>
<?php 
  echo ci_create_img('my');
?> <!--this is malaysia flay image -->
</button>
<button id="btn_hk" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" 
  onClick='location = "<?php echo url_realurl();?>/results/view/all/H"'>
<?php 
  echo ci_create_img('hk');
?><!--this is hongkong flay image-->
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and disable the button if it links to the current page. Example:

```
<?php
$countries = array(
    'my'    =>  '/results/view/all/M',
    'hk'    =>  '/results/view/all/H',
);
?>

<?php foreach ($countries as $code => $uri): ?>

    <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $uri): ?>
    <button class="disabled">
    <?php else: ?>
    <button onClick='location="<?php echo url_realurl().$uri; ?>"'>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo ci_create_img($code);?>
    </button>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You might want to `trim($uri, '/')` and `trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')` there to make sure there are no mistakes with slashes.

You could also append a `$_GET` variable to the link like `?country_code=hk` and read that instead:

```
<?php foreach ($countries as $code => $uri): ?>

    <?php if ($_GET['country_code'] === $code): ?>
    <button class="disabled">
    <?php else: ?>
    <button onClick='location="<?php echo url_realurl().$uri.'?country_code='.$code; ?>"'>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo ci_create_img($code);?>
    </button>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

There, you should also make sure to check if `isset($_GET['country_code'])`, and any other links on the page would most likely have to use the query string as well. I was trying to make this readable. I would just write a function for reading the url personally.

I prefer the first approach. Sorry, I had to craft it in my coding style, but hopefully you get the idea and this works for you.

Comment: Hi Wesley,
Thank you for your kind help.It helps a lot :)